# What progress has the US House's January 6th Select Committee made on drafting changes to the Electoral Count Act of 1887?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives, specific-legislation, capitol-riot-investigation

Towards the end of Face the Nation's [What comes next in the Jan. 6 hearings](https://youtu.be/eP7gust9RxQ?t=396) (06:36) CBS News' [Robert Costa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Costa_(journalist)) ends his list of questions he'd like answered with (my transcription aided by computer generated closed captions):

> But the bigger question; what legislation do they propose coming out of this? The committee has been unequivocal. They're going to draft new law. Is it *just changing the Electoral Count Act* to prevent January 6th 2025? If so, **the Senate has made some progress on that.**

While Costa is asking about other legislation, he seems certain that progress is being made on the Electoral Count Act itself.

**Question:** What progress has the January 6th select committee made on drafting changes to the [Electoral Count Act of 1887](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electoral_Count_Act)?

Comment: Under House and Senate rules, the committees with the authority for elections legislation are the House **Committee on House Administration** and the Senate **Committee on Rules and Administration**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What progress has the January 6th select committee made on drafting changes to the Electoral Count Act of 1887?

None.  One would not normally expect a committee to draft legislation before finishing its information gathering.  But in any event the committee was established for other purposes than drafting legislation.
In fact, it is [explicitly prohibited from drafting legislation by section 4(d) of its constituting resolution](https://january6th.house.gov/about):

> No Markup Of Legislation Permitted.—The Select Committee may not hold a markup of legislation.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_(legislation)):

> Markup (or mark-up) is the process by which a U.S. congressional committee or state legislative session debates, amends, and rewrites proposed legislation.

This is not inconsistent with the claim that the Senate has made progress toward changing the Electoral Count Act, because the Senate is a distinct chamber of the legislature.  It's also possible that members of the House have been working on new legislation, but any such work is separate from the work of the select committee.

To the extent that the select committee's work will contribute to changing the law, it will be that its reports (section 4(b)) will serve to inform the members who draft the new legislation.

Comment: related: Select Committee chairman Bennie Thompson: June 17, 2022: "Thank you again, Judge Luttig. As a part of the Select Committee's charge to make recommendations that are informed by other investigative findings, we will be reviewing the views shared by Judge Luttig and other experts on potential improvements to the Electoral Count Act, among a range of other initiatives." https://youtu.be/jzLNIDrjo-w?t=445 I think some progress was made

Comment: @uhoh if you take the broad view of "drafting," where preliminary preparatory work such as  investigation and issue analysis counts as progress, then yes, you could say that progress has been made.  Under a narrower view, they probably haven't actually written any proposed statutory language because they're forbidden from doing so.  If you're planning to drive from Paris to Berlin, does deciding whether or not to go through Belgium constitute "progress"?

Comment: Hmm... perhaps interviewing, consulting with and collecting sworn testimony several highly respected jurists and scholars and collecting and processing their input is not best characterized as "deciding whether or not to go through Belgium" but I understand the general idea :-)

Comment: Yes, CNN's [House lawmakers lay out proposal for legislation to prevent another January 6](https://edition.cnn.com/2022/09/19/politics/electoral-count-act-liz-cheney-zoe-lofgren/index.html) seems consistent with your answer.